# AMCharts candlestick chart, show entry/exit arrow

Tags: javascript, stock, amcharts, trading

Is it possible to show a little arrow at a specific price and time, indicating entries and exits in an AMChart? Something like:

[image]

If not, is there at least a way of creating custom drawing elements in the chart (circles, lines, squares) similarly to [this](http://www.amcharts.com/demos/stock-events/) but using a candlestick chart, not a line chart?

If none of that is possible, does anybody know about a JS library that's capable of doing so?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use events for this purpose: http://www.amcharts.com/demos/stock-events/
In the demo it's line chart,but events can be used with candlesticks as well.

Comment: Thanks @zeroin! I've created an event for a candle, but it's not showing up. How should I implement stockEvents for a Candlestick chart? I cannot find it in docs.

http://jsfiddle.net/jkHe6/

Comment: Stock Events is an exclusive feature of Stock Chart. They cannot be shown on regular Serial Chart.

Comment: Hi guys, I'm also interested if I could StockEvents display like vertical bars?